# Getting the width of a path drawn on a XAML canvas

Tags: xaml, canvas, windows-phone-8.1

I'm drawing a canvas programmatically, given a bunch of path data from somewhere else and adding it to the canvas as

```
// This is actually done more elaborately, but will do for now
PathFigureCollection figures = GetPathFigureCollection();

var path = new Path
{
    Data = new PathGeometry { Figures = figures },
    Fill = GetFill(),
    Stroke = GetStroke(),
    StrokeThickness = GetThickness()
};
MyCanvas.Children.Add(path);
```

Now, I have the canvas in a `ScrollViewer`, so I want to make sure that I can scroll all the way to reveal the entire path (actually path*s* - I have several, generated the same way) but no further. I tried this:

```
var drawingWidth = MyCanvas.Children
                       .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
                       .Max(e => Canvas.GetLeft(e) + e.ActualWidth);
MyCanvas.Width = drawingWidth;
```

This works well for some other elements (the drawing also has a few text blocks and ellipses), but for the paths both `Canvas.GetLeft(e)` and `e.ActualWith` (as well as some other things I tried like `e.RenderSize.Width` and  `e.DesiredSize.With`) all return `0`. Since the element that extends farthest to the right is a path, this results in a canvas that is too small.

**How do I get the width of the `Path` elements too?**

Comment: Are you trying to grab the values on initialize or after everything's rendered so measure and arrange has already happened? +1 good question.

Comment: @ChrisW. The textblocks and ellipses give sensical values, but I don't know how to verify that I'm actually in the right place in the render cycle. Any tips of checking and/or ensuring this are welcome!

Comment: Try just firing off your stuff after loaded, something like `private void thethingy_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {// do stuff.}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, found it!

Rewriting the LINQ query as a loop, I could cast paths to `Path`, and use `path.Data.Bounds.Right` as the right edge of that element.** I might be able to convert the code back to a LINQ query now that I know what I want to do (I always find them more readable than stateful loops...).

I found this when I, after having perused the link provided by [markE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke) where, as a side note, it was stated that

> If your design requirements allow more rough approximates, then you will find that cubic Bezier curves are always contained within their control points.

So, if I could find the right-most control point of all the path figures in my path, I would be home. Intellisense did the rest of the job for me :)